# putting selected values from the JSON

Tags: json, coldfusion

If I do the following on a query :

```
<cfdump var="#serializeJSON(findglobal)#">
```

I get the following:

```
{
    "COLUMNS": [
        "DELIVERED_PERCENTAGE",
        "UNIQUE_PERCENTAGE",
        "SPAM_PERCENTAGE",
        "DROP_PERCENTAGE",
        "REQUEST_PERCENTAGE",
        "BOUNCE_PERCENTAGE",
        "DEFERRED_PERCENTAGE",
        "PROCESSED_PERCENTAGE",
        "OPEN_PERCENTAGE",
        "BLOCKED_PERCENTAGE"
    ],
    "DATA": [
        [
            19.54,
            6.06,
            6.05,
            0.63,
            21.17,
            0.85,
            14.83,
            20.53,
            10.26,
            0.19
        ]
    ]
}
```

But I am using [Geikoboard](http://www.geckoboard.com/developers/custom-widgets/widget-types/pie-chart) which understand only the following format of JSON.
So I would like to have `DELIVERED_PERCENTAGE`, `UNIQUE_PERCENTAGE` for the label field below and all the values, like
19.54,6.06 etc for the value field below.

```
{ 
"item": [ 
{ 
"value": "11234", 
"label": "Webmail", 
"colour": "FFFF10AA" 
}, 
{ 
"value": "10736", 
"label": "Phone", 
"colour": "FFAA0AAA" 
}, 
{ 
"value": "230", 
"label": "Webmail", 
"colour": "FF5505AA" 
}, 
{ 
"value": "280", 
"label": "Webmail", 
"colour": "FF0000AA" 
} 
] 
}
```

Do I have to manually generate JSON ?

Comment: usually one would manipulate the data structure in CF to suit your requirement and then `SerializeJSON()` the CF struct at one go.

Comment: You may also want to try serializeJSON(findglobal, true) to set the serializeQueryByColumns flag. see: http://cfdocs.org/serializejson

Comment: Your dumped query looks nothing like the JSON you are trying to create. You need to give us more information. @Henry has told you the right path to go down, but if you need more help you need to explain how that query relates the the JSON you are trying to create.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for. Got it from some site; either Raymon Camden's  or Ben Nadel's.

```
    public array function queryToArray( required query qry ) {
    var columns = arguments.qry.getColumnNames();
    var OutputResult = [];

    for( var i = 1; i LTE qry.recordCount; i++ ) {
        var obj = {};

        for( var k = 1; k LTE arrayLen( columns ); k++ ) {
            structInsert( obj, columns[ k ], arguments.qry[ columns[ k ] ][ i ] );
        }

        arrayAppend(OutputResult, obj );
    }

    return OutputResult;
}
```

You would need to do something like this:

```
<cfset myJSON = queryToArray( myquery ) />
<cfoutput>#serializeJSON( myJSON )#</cfoutput>
```