# Using JavaScript to handle query data serialized by ColdFusion 9 neatly?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, coldfusion, titanium

ColdFusion's serializeJSON function sends a string like this:

```
{"COLUMNS":["COURSE","CONTID","CODE"],"DATA":[["Texting 101",41867,"T043"]]}
```

How do I access the data using javascript neatly?

```
var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
console.log(response["CODE"]); // this doesn't work of course, but is there any way?
console.log(response.DATA[0][1]) // this works but it's not readable
```

Is it possible to access the JSON data using the column names instead of the array positions? This is for Titanium Studio, so I have access to node (if that helps my cause).

Comment: try `serializeJSON(queryObj, true)` - http://cfdocs.org/serializejson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I defined the serializeQueryByColumns attribute of serializeJSON like so:

## #serializeJSON(cfQueryVar, true)#

However it will come out a little funky:

```
{"ROWCOUNT":1,
 "COLUMNS":["COURSE","CONTID","CODE"],
 "DATA":{
    "COURSE":["Texting 101","Sexting for Seniors","OMFGLOL","Columbus Day"],
    "CONTID":[41867,10736,23034,28012],
    "CODE":["T043","SFS","OMGL0100","CDSTD"]
 }}
```

But you can access it like so:

```
... Ti.UI.createHTTPClient ...
var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
label.text = "The 3rd Course is: ", response.DATA.COURSE[2];
```

---

### Citation

I got this from [Henry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/35634/henry) in the source [GuaravS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3217509/gauravs) gave
in his answer. I created a new answer because Henry's comment was a brief comment / not an answer, and I wanted to expand upon defining the
serializeQueryByColumns value in serializeJSON.

Answer (score 2):

I created [cfquery-to-json](https://github.com/iknowkungfoo/cfquery-to-json) to create alternate JSON formats for ColdFusion queries. Take a look at ArrayColleciton, which will convert the query object to an array of structs. The keys for the structs are the column names from the query.

`{
    "data":[
        {
            "course":"Texting 101",
            "contid":41867,
            "code":"T043"
        }
    ]
}`

This allows you to easily reference `data[x].course`.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the answer to the question [putting selected values from the JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22950028/putting-selected-values-from-the-json/22950747#22950747). You should then be able to access the column as expected.

```
public array function queryToArray( required query qry ) {
var columns = arguments.qry.getColumnNames();
var OutputResult = [];

for( var i = 1; i LTE qry.recordCount; i++ ) {
    var obj = {};

    for( var k = 1; k LTE arrayLen( columns ); k++ ) {
        structInsert( obj, columns[ k ], arguments.qry[ columns[ k ] ][ i ] );
    }

    arrayAppend(OutputResult, obj );
}

return OutputResult;
}
```

Access the function as below:

```
<cfset myJSON = queryToArray( myquery ) />
<cfoutput>#serializeJSON( myJSON )#</cfoutput>
```